# Wear OS custom fonts are not loaded at all

Tags: fonts, textview, wear-os

I have an Wear 2.0 Activity and a TextView which uses a custom font. When deploy the app to wear devices the font is not loaded, using real device LG Urbane 2(on simulator is loaded ok). Tried with different custom fonts. I have set the custom font in app style level and in activity layout textview. Text size is set to 16sp. AndroidX imports used.

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lalezar</item>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fontFamily="@font/lalezar"/>
```

Font used:​ Lalezar-Regular.ttf etc...

I am doing something wrong? Did anyone found a solution?

Comment: What Android version is your Urbane 2 on? Fonts in XML was introduced in 8.0 (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml), but AFAIK the Urbane 2 hasn't been updated past 7.1.1.

Comment: Latest and greatest it shows Wear OS 2.0

Comment: Not the Wear OS version, the Android version. In Android Studio, the Device dropdown at the upper-left of logcat will tell you; or, at the command line, `adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release`.

Comment: On some watches, it can also be found by going to Settings > System > About > Versions > Android OS.

Comment: @String yes 7.1.1 with wear OS 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not documented AFAICT, but it seems that specifying `fontFamily` in layout XML doesn't work on Wear OS.

Applying the font programmatically does work, however. Just get a reference to your `TextView` in Java/Kotlin, then:

```
myTextView.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.lalezar));
```